# What is the .NET 4.5 Windows Store App equivalent of FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, store

First off, I'm building a windows store application using a Flipview and I've created a custom context indicator similar to the first example you can find on this blog: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/08/24/A-CXAML-FlipView-Context-Indicator-for-Windows-8.aspx
To keep things short: I use a dependencyproperty to bind my flipview to my usercontrol.

My problem: the flipview that I use for my context indicator is databinded to the DefaultViewModel. Since I get the images in my flipview from a Web API, the collection in the DefaultViewModel will be null when the page is loaded. After I've succesfully loaded the images my DefaultViewModel["collection"] is filled and the flipview shows the images accordingly. My context indicator however remains unchanged and will only show the correct result if the page is loaded again.

The dependencyproperty in my usercontrol is as following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FlipviewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Flipview", typeof(FlipView), typeof(FlipviewIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(null, FlipView_Changed));

    private static void FlipView_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlipviewIndicator indicator = d as FlipviewIndicator;
        FlipView flipview = (e.NewValue as FlipView);
        indicator.ItemsSource = flipview.ItemsSource;
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Source = flipview;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem");
        indicator.SetBinding(FlipviewIndicator.SelectedItemProperty, binding);
    }
```

My question: is there a possible way to make my dependencyproperty notify the UI that my usercontrols needs to be rerenderd? I know it is possible in WPF by using the FrameworkPropertyMedata.AffectsRender like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FlipviewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Flipview",typeof(Flipview),typeof(FlipviewIndicator), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Color(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

In Windows Store apps however FrameworkPropertyMedata is no longer supported, is there an equivalent in store apps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about InvalidateArrange() ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatearrange.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Old question - but short answer is no. Windows Store Xaml (as at Windows 8.1) only has PropertyMetadata, however in the changed handler for the dependency property you can still call one of [InvalidateMeasure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatemeasure(v=vs.110).aspx), [InvalidateArrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatearrange(v=vs.110).aspx) or [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout(v=vs.110).aspx) as appropriate like you could in WPF.